# Is it possible to make it work without attaching foreign key to meta table in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I made a project with Spring Batch. However, due to the company's operating policy, foreign keys cannot be set in the meta table.

In this case, is it okay to make a table with only general columns and then insert data directly at the application level?

If there is another solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> due to the company's operating policy, foreign keys cannot be set in the meta table

How is your company planning to deal with data consistency without foreign keys? Your company's policies should really be reviewed.

The answer to your question is yes. You should be able to use Spring Batch without adding the foreign keys in its meta-data schema, but you obviously risk to have data inconsistencies and some undefined consequences in some cases.